# Why is the expression for the internal energy of molecules always valid in an ideal gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

I'm studying the first law of thermodynamics and I don really understand why the formula ${dU}$=${n}$${C_v}$${dT}$ is always valid. In the book "introduction to mechanic, matter and waves" by Uno Ingard, this relation is derived by supposing an constant volume process, which is understandable because then ${W}$=${0}$ and ${dQ}$=${dU}$, but then at some point it says that it is valid for every process. My question is, why is the reason I'm ${always}$ allowed to use this formula for ${dU}$ in an arbitrary process of an ideal gas?

Comment: The equation is valid only for an ideal gas.  For an ideal gas, U is not a function of V.

Comment: See this Q&A: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/384392/internal-energy-of-an-ideal-gas?rq=1

Comment: See [The cruelest equation in introductory thermodynamics](http://john.maloney.org/cruelest_equation.htm). The constant-volume heat capacity is just the name of a material property used in a simple ideal gas relation; it’s not a restriction on the relation’s use. Other material properties generally appear in the $dU$ equation, but they happen to cancel out here. This is a great source of frustration and confusion to new thermodynamics practitioners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let’s review the definition of heat capacity:
$$C_V= n\, c_V = \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V$$
In general, $U$ is a function of multiple thermodynamic variables, such as $U(T,V)$. That's why a partial derivative appears in the definition above.

However, according to the famous Joule experiment, in an ideal gas, $U$ depends only on $T$: $U(T)$. Therefore, for an ideal gas, the above definition simplifies to
$$C_V= n\, c_V = \frac{d U}{d T}$$
This is the equation you pointed out.

I hope it helps.